# App does not run on Android Marshmallow device on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am facing an error when I run the build in Android. I couldn't not find answer to my issue. Please help me.

[image]

Thank you in advance

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you have `com.github.clans.fab:1.6.2` two times in your gradle? And don't post a screen shot of your code and 27 hours to look on a error is a long time - might as well take a break.

Comment: oh i have removed it after screen shot but problem is same

Comment: post the your gradle and error not in screen shot

Comment: first image show error in post

Comment: did you tried invalidate caches / restart in you android studio if you add require dependencies correctly then you just restart android studio or else remove unwanted dependencies

Comment: yes i have tried but no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Windows 8.1 I tried deleting the folder .gradle in the application folder. Then I cleaned the project and build it again. IT WORKS FINE NOW.

Comment: i have macbook . how to delete it